# Android module is in release mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When setting the app to build in debug mode, each of the modules are being build in release mode. I checked "Build variants" and all the modules are set to "debug". Using Android 3.0.1. Gradle version 4.1.

**build.gradle (app module)**:

```
dependencies {
     compile project(path: ':logic')
}
```

Comment: can you share all your gradle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the default build type block as Android studio by default configures the build type to release.

```
buildType {

release { 
    ...
  }

}
```

But you need to share you full build.gradle file to get a specific answer as the value may be overridden by some other setting either in the build.gradle file in the project root or main folder.